# Relative files paths in doxygen-generated documentation

Tags: doxygen, relative-path

I am using Doxygen 1.7.4 for Windows.

In the *File List* page of generated documentation I'd like to see relative paths.
I have set `FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES`, to have something more, than just filename without path, but this gives full, absolute paths.

I want only paths relative to project directory. I know, that I can use `STRIP_FROM_PATH` but I have problem with wildcards. I need that kind of path-stripping, because this project is made on multiple PCs (as git repo), so paths can be different.

Is it possible to use wildcards for this setting, or do I have to set doxyfile for each workstation with part of absolute path to strip?

---

Edit:

I've found something like what I need on the doxygen website: `STRIP_FROM_PATH      = $(QTDIR)/`

Maybe it is possible to use one of doxyfile's variables?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure about Windows, but on Linux and OS X I can produce outputs in the file list like

- src/Utils.cpp [code]
- src/Utils.h [code]
- src/VectorMath.h [code]
- test/src/test.cpp [code]

By setting `FULL_PATH_NAMES` to `YES` and `STRIP_FROM_PATH` to `../..` (i.e. the directory path of project's root which is two directories up from where I'm building the docs). You may need to swap the directory separator to the windows one.

You'll also need to watch out that you update the Doxyfile if you move the docs around.

Comment: +1 Tested and works just fine on Windows, too. The forward slash `/` is a perfectly valid directory separator on Windows, so no changes are necessary.