# How can i use relative path names in Doxygen configuration

Tags: path, config, doxygen, relative-path

I have my doxygen in my /utils directory, and my source is in another directory in the root(`/code_with_doxygen`), how could i make a relative path name for that since it's in a repository that will be on different places on other computers. I can't document the whole root because i don't want the directory `/code_without_doxygen` build too.

the project tree looks like this:

```
root
    utils
    code
        code_with_doxygen
        code_without_doxygen
    documentation
```

right now i have the settings, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = ../
```

i can't seem to figure it out with: [Relative files paths in doxygen-generated documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261366/relative-files-paths-in-doxygen-generated-documentation)

Comment: i fixed it in the .bat file. i navigated to the root map, then i run doxygen from there while i add some configurations to the doxygen_config with the %cd% command. then it looks like this: "( type utils\config_doxygen.txt & echo INPUT=%cd%\code\code_with_doxygen\  ) | doxygen.exe -"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relative paths depend on the directory from which directory you are executing doxygen. For example if you have the following project tree:

```
+ project_root
     + documentation
         + config
             - doxyfile
         + pictures
         + output
         - run_doxygen.bat
     + code
         + code_with_doxygen
         + code_without_doxygen
```

In this case all relative paths have they root in the folder "documentation" because you are running the script "run_doxygen.bat" from this folder. So you would set the `INPUT` tag in the "doxyfile" to

```
INPUT = ./../code
```

and the `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` tag in the doxyfile to

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = ./output
```

The misleading thing is that even if the doxyfile is in the subfolder "config" the paths are NOT relative to the location of the doxyfile because the paths are relative to the location from where doxygen is called. In this case it is the folder "documentation" because this is the location of the script which is calling doxygen.

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen allows for including files into doxyfile. You can generate a file using a script before actually calling doxygen. The content of this file has to look like this:

```
INPUT += path1
INPUT += path2
...
```

You seem to to run Linux, I don't know the correct bash-commands.

The file has to be integrated into your doxyfile:

```
INPUT = (project path)
@INCLUDE = generated filename
```

This will lead to doxygen using the content of your generated file.

Answer (score 0):

@gmug was right. Don't forget to add comment blocks in your code as [specified by doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#specialblock) For python I needed to add this: `"""@package docstring"""` at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to use relative paths in my `doxygen.cfg` file by setting `INPUT` to a string or set of strings. For example:

```
INPUT                  = "." "src"
```

will tell `doxygen` to look in both the current directory and its subdirectory, `$HERE/src`.